# Seperate or space between the two values in one cell in Datatable (Laravel 8)

Tags: php, datatable, laravel-8

I have a query from Database which is John and Mary under display_name. For (ID 1 = John)(ID 2 = Mary) I have a data on view that contain two values or ID in one cell using AJAX Datatable based on this picture.

[image: Cell in Datatable]

[image: Database ID 1 : John , ID 2 : Mary]

How can I seperate or make a space between this two values that bring ID on view Datatables ? I want to make "John Mary" instead of "JohnMary" in one cell column.

Here is my Index datatable code:

```
->addColumn('roles', function($record){    
                $data='';
                if($record->role()->get()){
                    foreach ($record->role()->get() as $role){
                        $data .= $role->display_name;
                    }
                }
                return $data;
            })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a space after your name will do the trick:

```
$data .= $role->display_name . ' ';
```

Comment: how about break the line ?

Comment: Change to ' ' to "\r" or "\n" if you want to break the line.
Or even '<br/>' if you need a HTML break line.

Comment: All of it doesn't work. '<br/>' read as text

Comment: you can use {!! nl2br($data) !!} or {!! $data !!} in your views. It will render the html code. But remember this is not safe practice when a user can input some data in this variable.